# General version of Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated algebra over a ring $R$ and let $\{s_1,\dots, s_n\}$ be a generating set. An element $s\in M$ defines a linear transformation via
$$s(s_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{i,j}s_j$$
Define $A\in M_n(R)$ by $A=(a_{i,j})$. Then the following holds:
$$s\pmatrix{s_1\\s_2\\\vdots\\s_n}=A\pmatrix{s_1\\s_2\\\vdots\\s_n}$$
or
$$(sI_n-A)\pmatrix{s_1\\s_2\\\vdots\\s_n}=0$$
I have seen a claim that from the equality above it follows that $det(sI_n-A)=0$ and that this is actually a more general version of Cramer's rule. I don't see why.

Comment: I don’t understand how an element $s \in M$ is supposed to defines a linear transformation $M \to M$: How do the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ relate to $s$?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Sorry for the confusion, $M$ is an algebra and so elements define linear transformation simply by multiplication. The $a_{i,j}$ are the coefficients of $s \cdot s_i$